# Searching by multiple fields using meteor-easy-search

Tags: search, meteor

I'm trying to implement a search by two db fields using [meteor-easy-search](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/)
package, however, I can't seem to find a way of doing it. Here is the problem:

I have a schema:

```
{
  name: String,
  location: String
}
```

I have two input fields on my form:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="location">
```

EasySearch provides a way of searching only by a single value:

```
 EasySearch.search('people', name, .....
```

Is there a way I can pass an Object to search method, so I can write my own 'query' inside of EasySearch.createSearchIndex()?

Moreover, I will need to convert "location" into a geo-spiral index and search for "a name within a radius of this location"

I know this can be done directly with MongoDB or ElasticSearch, but I would like to roll with meteor-easy-search, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the [meteor-easy-search documentation](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/javascript-api/), you can initialize a default query in the `EasySearch.createSearchIndex()` call and also add several search fields, like this:

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('people', {
  'field' : ['name', 'location'],
  'collection' : People,
  'limit' : 20,
  'use' : 'elastic-search'
  'props' : {
    'anyField' : true
  },
  'query' : function (searchString, opts) {
    // Default query that is used for searching
    var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);

    return query;
  }
});
```

Comment: Right, what this does it allowing me to search by only one input field within 'name' and 'location' db fields, but I need to search by two input fields in their respective db fields.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this problem? I am also looking for the solution..thanks